# how to expose my nodejs cli module in different environments

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm building a cli using nodejs, called `xygcli`, everything works fine, but after I published it, I got some peoples telling me that they couldn't find the command 
`"xygcli not found (zsh)"`

I'm sure that they use `npm install -g` to install this cli, but still have the same issue,

so is there a way to make sure that my cli works after install on any OS/environment/docker ?

Comment: They could use `npx`, a feature of more recent versions of npm that lets you run CLI commands without having to install them first https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

Comment: Any difference in platforms for the folks having trouble from those who aren't? Eg Windows/Linux/Mac?  Also, for the global commands to work,the global install location has to be on their PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned our that some users has `node` command defined and the others has `nodejs` command defined without a symbolic link between the 2, 
so I changed the shebang lines of my cli to be:

```
#!/bin/sh
':' //; exec "$(command -v nodejs || command -v node)" "$0" "$@"
```